# Rails Controller - refresh page same as if I hit the refresh on my browser

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have inherited a Rails code base that I do not fully understand. We have a requirement to, when the user hits Submit, render ON THAT PAGE the set of validation failures the user put into the form. I cannot redirect to any other page - we must remain on the page which contains the form upon which they put the invalid input.

Here is my method

```
  def tpr_bulk_update

    updated, date_died = update_tprs #it returns 0,0 when there are validation fails
    if updated == 0 && date_died == 0
        flash.now[:notice] = 'A bunch of errors occurred'
    #Here I need to refresh the page. I do not especially want to redirect. 
    #I want this to perform exactly the same as me hitting the refresh button on my browser. 
    #The initial form loaded via a very complicated codebase that I do not understand exactly. 
    #I do have available to me the params from the initial call - but it seems to me hitting refresh on 
    #the browser implicitly handles repassing to this method with the SAME PARAMS I CAME IN WITH.... 
    #AND it shows my flash.now. So then, I want to refresh the page the same mechanism the browser uses, 
    #because this is what demonstrably meets my requirement
    elsif !date_died
        redirect_to tprs_index_vod_assets_path
    else
       flash[:notice] = "One or more TPR assets were not given valid future dates, so those invalid dates did not save".html_safe
        redirect_to tprs_index_vod_assets_path
    end
  end
```

The issue is I see no way to do this. Perhaps the browser invoking refresh uses javascript that is impossible to inline in my rails controller?

```
redirect_to :back
```

fails on account that the set of params I came in with are not populated - it explodes.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js {render inline: "location.reload();" }
end
```

My method does not output javascript, and neither will it ever output javascript - that is a requirement for the system.

I need whatever is equivalent to the refresh operation my browser (Chrome) performs when I press "Refresh". I want that to happen right after I set my flash.now message. How can I capture what Chrome/what hitting refresh actually does? And how can I perform it within my controller?

Comment: Anything that happens server-side is a reaction to a request by the client-side. This request is caused by one of three things: user clicks a link (GET), user submits a form (usually GET or POST), script makes AJAX request (usually GET or POST). The former two cause navigation to what the server sends back, the AJAX response doesn't. Showing server-side validation on a form page simply means that when the form is submitted with invalid data, the server adds the error messages to the form view and sends it back. Refreshing the browser causes it to repeat the last navigation request.

Comment: So my guess is if validation fails, you set the flash messages, then `redirect_to [form_view]`

Comment: @ChrisG I tried this - 

redirect_to tpr_bulk_update(params.permit!)

All the params from my original POST are there - but it keeps adding a member in params called :id that I cannot take off or do anything with. The result is that it tries to go to a different method (show) using that id. It doesn't exhibit the same functionality as simply clicking refresh in the browser. I was hoping I could circumvent using redirect_to because it seems to me it has no mechanism at all to re-do a POST like hitting Refresh does.

Comment: @ChrisG I wonder is there some way to circumvent the rails maze of redirects and routes therein? Like if I really could, I would just literally inline javascript location.reload()

Comment: You can use `render <new/edit>' or whatever your view that have the form. That will give you the exact feel of page refresh and you will have the flash message and model validation error as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what AJAX was designed for. By sending an asyncronous request you can send data to the server without reloading the page and update the page with the response. In Rails you can use Server Side Concerns to simply replace a chunk of contents with a rendered view.

Since you don't actually have an example of the form or controller this is a simplefied example that demonstrates the concept:

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @thing = Thing.new
  end

  def create
    @thing = Thing.new(thing_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @thing.save    
        format.js
      else
        format.js { render :new }
      end
     end
    end
  end
end
```

```
# things/_form.html.erb
# remote: true is the default - its just added for extra clarity here
<%= form_with(model: @thing, remote: true, id: 'my-special-form') do |form| %>
  <% if @thing.errors %>
    # .. display the errors
  <% end %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

```
# things/new.html.erb
<%= render partial: 'form' %>
```

```
// things/new.js.erb

// Since we want to extract the children of the form element
// we use DOMParser to create a fragment
const node = new DOMParser().parseFromString(
  "<%= j render(partial: 'form') %>",  // rails renders the template
  "text/html"
);
// Find form on page and replace its contents
document.getElementById('my-special-form').innerHTML = node.querySelector('form').innerHTML;

// @todo set flash message
```

```
// things/create.js.erb
window.location = "<%= thing_path(@thing) %>";
```

The way that this works is that Rails UJS listens for submit events on any element with the `data-remote` attribute. Instead of the normal submit it will send an XHR request with the `Content-Type: application/javascript` header.

After rails is finished rendering and reponding with your js.erb view it is sent back to the client and Rails UJS takes the response and evals it by popping it into a script tag.